# php background process in windows environment

Tags: php

am using windows-7 OS and wamp server.
i have 2 php files trigger.php,background.php. 
i want to run background.php in background .i have to call this file from trigger.php .

i tried below methods.

i added this code in trigger.php

```
    $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
   $oExec = $WshShell->Run("C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php-win.exe -f C:/wamp/www/background.php", 0, false);
```

but my background.php is not getting called.

how i can do this?

any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: make sure Windows Script Host is installed properly, and if you use IIS check for the security settings of COM. Refer to MS sites for this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
}
```

in this case your `$cmd` would be `"php C:/wamp/www/path/to/background.php"`

Comment: thanks for reply krishnanunni. in your function where should i include code to call my file background.php , what is $cmd means?

Comment: hi krishnanunni , used your method in trigger.php. but, trigger.php not stops from running(executing). my backgroung.php contains only one insert statement to add data to table. hope this will not take much time to execute.

Comment: call exit() after calling this method

Comment: this will not wait for the background.php to complete. this will just start executing background.php and leave. $cmd is hust a param, command to execute for starting a background process.  This was a 4.x version usage. Goto http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#35731 for more information. the page contains lot information how to do this

Comment: included exit after calling execInBackground() function. but same problem. my trigger.php is taking too much of time to execute.

Comment: how do you let the background script return a value?

Answer (score 1):

i changed the function as below,

```
$cmd = 'C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.exe C:\wamp\www\email3.php';

function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B " . $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
}
```

and , its works for me. :)

Comment: If i want to pass parameter then how should i pass? I have tried using querystring like C:\wamp\www\email3.php?id=value but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```php
function execInBackground(string $cmd)
{
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows") {
        pclose(popen("start /B {$cmd}", "r"));
        return;
    }

    exec("{$cmd} > /dev/null &");
}

$phpBinPath = defined('PHP_BINARY') ? PHP_BINARY : '/usr/bin/php';
$fileToRun = __DIR__ . '/sleep.php';
$cmd = "'{$phpBinPath}' '{$fileToRun}'";

execInBackground($cmd);

echo 'Executou!!!';
```