# Call proc_open without wait for response

Tags: php, connection, fsockopen, proc-open

As I have to explain why my question different then the question [php background process in windows environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810152/php-background-process-in-windows-environment), the explanation is:

First of all, I want to run a shell script via proc_open in php, not via exec.

> Also conceptually its a isolated thread in my mind(if it succeded),
>   which will run in backend, populating a log file or a queued db table
>   from which I can poll my result.

---

I have a proc_open code, which eventually runs a php file in cli:

File: proc-open.php

```
    $descriptorspec = array(
       0 => array("pipe", "r"),
       1 => array("pipe", "w"),
       2 => array("file", "midirectory_path/error-output.txt", "a")
    );
    $process = proc_open("php -f myphpfile.php", $descriptorspec, $pipes, "midirectory_path");
    if (!is_resource($process)) {
        die ('Could not execute RUNMYSCRIPT');
    }

    sleep(10);
    fwrite($pipes[0], 'q');
    $result = fread($pipes[1], 1);
    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    proc_close($process);
```

And I want to hit this line of code but do not want to wait for the response:
File: proc-call.php

```
$url = 'http://example.com/proc-open.php';
$parts=parse_url($url);
$fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$out = "GET ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
$out.= "Content-Length: 0"."\r\n";
$out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $out);
fclose($fp);
```

But it is not calling the proc_open and I can't see any php cli in my task manager.
I hit in browser as http://example.com/proc-call.php, it return 200.

Need help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php background process in windows environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810152/php-background-process-in-windows-environment)

Comment: I have a different opinion here, I don't want to run anything in command prompt, rather I am more interested in a LONG RUNNING JOB, any idea how such a thing can be leveraged using PHP