# Website keeps users waiting even after their file upload is completely finished

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

The plan: I am coding for a web site on which the users need to upload large JSON files (50MB - 500MB+). These JSON files contain information about the users. The site must retrieve these information and after that store it on a MySQL database that I have created. I am using JSON machine *(https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine)* instead of JSON decode *(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)* to parse these large JSON files faster. So the process goes like this:

1) The user uploads his own large JSON file.

2) I parse his JSON and store his data temporarily on my machine.

3) I send the data from my machine to MySQL database.

(I have also code for the last two steps combined).

2-3) After uploading is finished I parse the large JSON and store the data directly to MySQL.

Now the problem: I want the users to be occupied only for the first step (the upload), after that I want to let them free and able to navigate to other pages of my website even if the other two (or one) step(s) haven't been completed yet. So my problem is the time. The last two steps might take some minutes or even a lot of hours and I don't want to keep users waiting after they finish the upload of their JSON file.

My solutions: When this problem came up I tried to find a way to run the last two processes on the background and I found this *([php background process in windows environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810152/php-background-process-in-windows-environment))* although it didn't work out. After that, I tried AJAX. I thought if the page does not reload, the user will be able to navigate, but that didn't work either. The page now does not reload when a user uploads a JSON but the user is still occupied for the whole duration of the three steps. Also, ignore_user_abort() *(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)* is not a solution because in my case I don't want to let the users abort the page, I want them to keep navigating.

I have to mention that the code is working properly, it gets users JSON files and after that it parses and stores everything to my MySQL database exactly like I want it to do, but it just keeps the users waiting for hours because of the thousands of inserts it has to execute for the database, especially if they have a very large JSON file. I have tried many things and I still don't know what I have to do to fix this problem. Αny kind of help is welcome!

Comment: have you looked at just starting a thread? https://www.php.net/manual/en/thread.start.php

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Yes, I looked up on threads, and this might be the right thing to do but I hope I could find something easier to be honest. Thanks for sharing your opinion.

Comment: Ajax is perhaps only a solution if the user stays on the same page. Therefore I would recommend to take a look on Websockets. The user can upload his data to your machine and then navigate to other pages on your site. When the following steps are completed you can send back a notification to the user via the Websocket.

Comment: Here's a general process you can try to follow: 1. commit the upload to your server's local file system by moving the file's location from the local temp directory to a more permanent one; 2. dispatch a background process using PHP's `curl` library, or by performing an `exec()` call to perform some other command-line based request dispatching, or by using a scheduled background service configured through the OS, and have this background process handle the uploaded file; and 3. allow the primary process to end after dispatching the background process.

Comment: Hello there, just a slight correction - JSON Machine is not any faster than json_decode. It just does not run out of memory. It is in fact about an order of magnitude slower. The actual strength shows when you need to parse infinite-like JSONs.

Comment: Hello @FilipHalaxa, thanks for the correction. To be honest, I read this readme (https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine#on-parser-efficiency) and that's why I said that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some more searching, I found out that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810152/php-background-process-in-windows-environment) isn't the best, but it's close to what I used in my case. So I combined it with some examples [of this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) and I changed it to that:

```
function execInBackground($cmd) { // Function creation.
  $descriptorspec = array(
     0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from.
     1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to.
     2 => array("pipe", "w")   // stderr is a file to write to.
  );

  $pipes = array(); // Empty array

  if(substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ // If your are on a Windows enviroment.
    $process = proc_open("start /B ". $cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes); // proc_open() needs three arguments,
// the command,
// the descriptorspec array
// and the pipes empty array.

  }
  else { // If you are not on Windows enviroment.
    exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &"); // Same as proc_open, but not for Windows.
  }
  proc_close($process); // Finally close the process you opened.
}
```

And I use this to run my function:

```
execInBackground('C:/xampp/php/php.exe C:/xampp/htdocs/Your/Path/To/Your/file.php');
```

Now my users are able to navigate to any other page of my website after their upload is completed. They don't have to wait for parsing and database insertion to end because now these procedures executes on my computer's background.

Comment: This is OK if you are on shared hosting. However, if you have control of your deployment servers, a queue would be better. Have a look at [this list](http://queues.io/).